# difference between netstat and ss in linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, netstat

In linux, netstat command tells us information of active sockets in system.

I understand that `netstat` uses `/proc/net/tcp` to acquire the system network information.

Since `netstat` man page says that netstat is obsolete, so we should use 'ss'.

```
NOTE
   This program is obsolete.  Replacement for netstat is ss.   Replacement
   for  netstat -r is ip route.  Replacement for netstat -i is ip -s link.
   Replacement for netstat -g is ip maddr.
```

I have discovered that `ss` performs similar functionality but it does not use
`/proc/net/tcp` to acquire system network information.

Now I am curious how `ss` gets system network socket information?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It gets them from kernel space directly using [Netlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) which uses the classic [sockets](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356) API.

Comment: thank you, it would be better if there is more detailed information about how ss queries information to kernel space

Answer (score 29):

I've made a [comparison table (in Google Docs)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_iZPZv6j2LqDA2TynvhKPGlRNBuaVcb6_hXfNhdPRzE/edit) ([light HTML link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRkIfCk6z95RRPiYuRKM0C_8PzmKPAyGW3dK6NWsRHFiAAo-M9-X3RIcR47-pa8Eyc5mVj8Uniz_qOa/pubhtml)) for converting between `netstat` and `ss` arguments. It's too big to include and update it here.

[image: google doc screenshot]

The short version of difference between short arguments is:

Arguments that require attention:
`r N i g M W T v C F c A U 2 f`

Arguments that are safe to leave as is:
`h V l a n Z s p e o 4 6 x t u S w`

Comment: Fantastic! Bookmarked for later reference.

Answer (score 21):

`ss` is included in iproute2 package and is the substitute of the `netstat`. `ss` is used to dump socket statistics. It shows information similar to `netstat`. It can display more TCP and state information than other tools. It is a new, incredibly useful and faster (compared to netstat) tool for tracking TCP connections and sockets.

Answer (score 11):

Check out the source for ss:

https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/misc/ss.c

Basically it directly queries the kernel and can respond much faster than `netstat`.

Answer (score 9):

`ss` is a utility used to investigate sockets in Linux and Unix systems. It shows information similar to `netstat` and able to dump socket statistics.

But `netstat` cannot be replaced full by `ss`. Some `netstat` commands correspond better to `ip` command.

```
    $ netstat -r   replaced by  $ ip route
    $ netstat -i   replaced by  $ ip -s lin
    $ netstat -g   replaced by  $ ip maddr
```

I would say the "older" `netstat` command can be replaced with both `ss` and `ip` commands.