# python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, sockets, server, httpserver

When running this command

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

I am getting below listed error

> socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Comment: Some other process running on your system is already listening on port 8000.

Comment: maybe open in web browser `localhost:8000` to see what program uses this port

Comment: BTW: sometimes system (Windows/Linux/MacOS) blocks port for some short time after closing program and you have to wait before you can run the same program again.

Answer (score 1):

That message clearly tells that port 8000 is already in use, just use another port or kill another process that uses port 8000 first.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and help .my issue got resolved by installing some ipks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a process is already using that port. So you will want to find which process is listening on that port and kill it

**Linux**

To check which process is using the port on Linux, you can install net-tools and use the command:
`netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':[Port Number]'`

Then using the PID (Process ID) you got from the previous command you can kill the program with the following:

`kill -9 [PID]`

**Windows**

If you are on Windows you can find the process by using:

`netstat -a -n -o | find "[Port Number]"`

Then you can just hop into Task Manager and kill the process.

I hope this helps

Comment: I'd like to comment the Linux part: `netstat` is deprecated (since 2011?) - use `ss` instead. On recent systems it is not even installed by default: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763376/difference-between-netstat-and-ss-in-linux. `kill -9` is a to be used only when regular ways to stop a process fail. It does not give the process a chance to clean up. Another reason is if the killed process is part of a systemd service, it might get restarted.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and help my issue got resolved by installing some ipks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which python version you are using but please check [SimpleHTTPServer — Simple HTTP request handler python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)

I have tried :: `python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1` it worked instead of `SimpleHTTPServer`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and help .my issue got resolved by installing some ipks.